# Intuition behind the Bolzano-Weierstrass property

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have a real analysis final exam coming up, and one thing we've discussed is equivalent compactness statements (if $X$ is sequentially compact, $X$ is compact, etc). One equivalent condition is $X$ having the Bolzano-Weierstrass property (for all $A\subset X$ with $|A| = \infty$, $A$ has limit points in $X$).

Is there an easy way to think about this? I'm having trouble thinking about how this could imply compactness of $X$, or even what this means generally.

Comment: You can think of it as being the space doesn't have much room.

Comment: What is your intuition for "compactness"?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well, in an $\mathbb{R^n}$ space, simply closed and bounded. Generally, if each element in $X$ has some subsequence which converges to a different element in $X$, then it is compact (sequential compactness). The Bolzano-Weierstrass property confuses me a bit.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So I suppose that is part of my question - if $A$ is infinite, yet somehow contained in $X$, how could that possibly prove that $X$ is compact?

Comment: The B-W property seems to be easily imply sequential compactness.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews hmm...would it be wrong to take $A\equiv X$ so that for all $x_n\in A\equiv X$, $x_n$ has a limit point in $X$? Is that a useful way to think about the relation or no?

Answer (score 2):

In general topological spaces these notions are all distinct. Bolzano-Weierstrass is then called "limit point compact", sequentially compact is the usual name, and compact is the finite subcover definition.

They are all equivalent in metric spaces,but outside of that things get weird. 
There are compact spaces that are not sequentially compact (like $[0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}$ in the product topology) and sequentially compact spaces are always limit point compact (if $A$ is infinite we can always find a sequence $a_n$ of different elements in $A$, and the limit of a convergent subsequence then is a limit point of $A$). The reverse holds, e.g., in first countable spaces $T_1$-spaces: there having a sequence (say of all different points  $(x_n)_n$ the set $A = \{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is infinite so has a limit point $x$. Then we have a decreasing local base at $x$, $(U_n)_n$ (like $B(x, \frac{1}{n})$ in a metric space) and picking an increasing sequence of indices from the intersections $U_n \cap A$ gets us a convergent subsequence. Compact does always imply limit point compact (as an infinite subset $A$ of $X$ without a limit point is closed and discrete and gives us a cover without a finite subcover). But a space can be limit point compact *and* sequentially compact without being compact, the most classical example of this being the ordinal space $\omega_1$ in the order topology.

Compactness has the nicest preservation properties (the best known of these being that any product of compact spaces will be compact (Tychonoff theorem), while even a product of 2 limit point compact spaces can fail to be limit point compact. Sequential compactness is a bit stronger: there we can take countable products and stay sequentially compact. Topology was first developed within metric spaces (subsets of Euclidean spaces e.g.) and so it took some time to see that the notions that are equivalent for metric spaces are in fact quite differently behaved among general spaces. It did bring a lot of interesting theorems and problems though.